# Regular Expression Limitation with Paragraph Replacement

Tags: regex, libreoffice-writer

I got into a situation where it seems like there is no way forward. 
[image]

After : there is paragraph break which I want to remove but when I search using :$, it searches just fine but no matter what I put in replace box, it doesn't remove the paragraph break.

I found that When I search :$ then it will search a paragraph break after : but won't remove the paragraph mark.
[Tabs, newlines, paragraphs \t \n $](https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/How_Tos/Regular_Expressions_in_Writer#Tabs.2C_newlines.2C_paragraphs_.5Ct_.5Cn_.24)

So any alternative to this. I tried with Alt Search as well but it won't let me do the thing either.

Comment: Instead of an image of the text, please post the actual text that needs to be replaced.

Comment: The text is in Hindi language. And its a copy paste from some source, I wanted to create epub file out of it for my Kindle and so I was doing the formatting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$ is a "zero-width-lookahead-assertion" functionally while \p is denoting the next-paragraph-mark itself. Found groups (parentheses used in the search string) are denoted \1, \2 and so on in AltSearch.

Seraching for (:)\p the correct substrings were found - also if the text was inside a right to left sequence. Using \1 as replace string then replaced the combined finding with the colon allone and the next-paragraph-mark was deleted.

[AskLibre Answer](https://ask.libreoffice.org/en/question/82837/regular-expression-limitation-with-paragraph-replacement/?answer=82842#post-id-82842)

Answer (score 0):

Using Alt Search, search for the following:

```
:\p
```

Leave the replace box empty, then press Replace All.

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work. I have found the solution at asklibre though. Will post here.